# Transparency in the ends of a border right in CSS

Tags: css, border, transparent, linear-gradients

I have to create a border-right on td tag which is transparent only in the ends i.e the border must be of the width 1px in the center and keep decreasing till the end. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you please create fiddle?

Comment: @anshul must include the desired behavior, the shortest code necessary to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

This might what you're looking for

```
border-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
```

Comment: No Devign, it didn't help. Though it will be done in a way close to your solution only.